# how to convert the Tue Jan 31 17:38:10 +0000 2017 format to date format in R?

Tags: r, datetime-format

I tried `ISOdatetime()` but it's not working.

```
error:  argument "min" is missing, with no default
```

for example: `Tue Jan 31 17:38:10 +0000 2017 -> 31/01/2017 or 31-01-2017`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `strptime`

```
format(strptime(str1, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%OS%z %Y"), "%d/%m/%Y")
#[1] "31/01/2017"
```